# How to ordering Yajra Datatable as a date instead of string

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, laravel

does anyone know how to make column "Tanggal Dibuat" (created_at) ordered as date? Currently when i clicking on it. the date wasnt show the right order i think because the created_at was readed as string, not a date. I'm using Laravel 8 & Yajra Datatable. here my UsersDatatables code in my datatable folder

```
public function dataTable($query)
{
    return datatables()
        ->eloquent($query)->addIndexColumn()
        ->editColumn('created_at', function($data) {
            $formatedDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $data->created_at)->format('d/m/Y'); return $formatedDate; })
        ->editColumn('updated_at', function($data) {
                $formatedDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $data->updated_at)->format('d/m/Y'); return $formatedDate; })
        ->editColumn('is_active', function ($item) {
                return $item->is_active == 1 ? 'AKTIF' : 'NON-AKTIF';
        })
        ->addColumn('action', function($item) {
                return '
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Aksi
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                                <li>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="'. route('user.edit', $item->id) .'">
                                        Ubah 
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="'. route('user.delete', $item->id) .'" class="dropdown-item text-danger" data-confirm-delete="true">
                                        Delete
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ';
    });
}

public function query(User $model)
{
    return $model::with('role');
}

public function html()
{
    return $this->builder()
                ->scrollY(725)
                ->scrollCollapse(false)
                ->setTableId('users-table')
                ->serverSide(false)
                ->languagePaginateNext('→')
                ->languagePaginatePrevious('←')
                ->columns($this->getColumns())
                ->minifiedAjax()
                ->orderBy(0, 'asc');
}

protected function getColumns()
{
    return [
        Column::make('DT_RowIndex')
              ->title('No')
              ->addClass('text-center')
              ->orderable(false),
        Column::make('name')
              ->addClass('text-center')
              ->title('Nama'),
        Column::make('role.name')
              ->addClass('text-center')
              ->title('Role'),
        Column::make('is_active')
              ->addClass('text-center')
              ->title('Status'),
        Column::make('created_at')
              ->addClass('text-center')
              ->title('Tanggal Dibuat'),
        Column::computed('action')
              ->addClass('text-center')
              ->title('Opsi')
              ->exportable(false)
              ->printable(false)
              ->addClass('text-center')
    ];
}

protected function filename()
{
    return 'User_' . date('YmdHis');
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i have found "my way" to do this, the first step is convert the data created_at to unix timestamp format (integer) then display it as normal date

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public function query(User $model)
{
    return $model::with('role')->orderBy('created_at', 'asc');
}
```

Comment: could you explain your code please for the benefit of future readers of this question? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yajra Datatables uses jquery datatables on the front end. As you can see from here, you can ordering through existing functions: [See](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/blob/master/src/DataTableAbstract.php#L662C34-L662C34)

The function that suits you might be `orderData()`: https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderData

Do it like this:

```php
public function html()
{
    return $this->builder()
                ->scrollY(725)
                ->scrollCollapse(false)
                ->setTableId('users-table')
                ->serverSide(false)
                ->languagePaginateNext('→')
                ->languagePaginatePrevious('←')
                ->columns($this->getColumns())
                ->minifiedAjax()
                ->orderBy(4, 'desc') // Order by the 4th column (created_at) in descending order
                ->orderData([4, 0]); // Specify that the 4th column (created_at) should be treated as date for ordering
}
```

Comment: i got error BadMethodCallException
Method Yajra\DataTables\Html\Builder::orderData does not exist. any other way?